# Catching use of return without parentheses in R

Tags: r

I just tracked down a silly bug in some R code that I had written.  The bug was equivalent to this:

```
brokenEarlyReturn = function(x=TRUE) {
    if (x) return   # broken with bare return
    stop("Should not get here if x is TRUE. x == ", x)
}

brokenEarlyReturn(TRUE)
# Error in brokenEarlyReturn(TRUE) : 
#    Should not get here if x is TRUE. x == TRUE
```

The problem is that instead of `return()` I had just a bare `return` without the following parentheses.  This causes the if statement be roughly equivalent to `if (x) constant`, where the body is a bareword that performs no action.  In this case, the bareword is the definition of the `return` function itself, and the function continues rather than returning.  The correct version would look like this:

```
workingEarlyReturn = function(x=TRUE) {
    if (x) return()   # parentheses added to return
    stop("Should not get here if x is TRUE. x == ", x)
}
```

It makes sense that R requires parentheses after return, but as a C programmer I'm likely to occasionally forget to add them.   Usually there would be a parsing error if they are omitted, but in this case of a bare return in the body of an if statement there is not.

Assuming I want the ability to put a "guard" statement at the top of a function that will return without a value if some condition is not met, how I can avoid making this error in the future?   Or at least, how can I make it easier to track down this error when I do make it?   Is there some "expression has no effect" warning that I can turn on?

Comment: Can you use `if (!x) return(invisible())`?

Comment: You can do the opposite. `if(!x) #carry out function else stop()`